# How to find the child element on hover using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am try to create the menu in hover I want to slide the sub menus using jQuery,
I tried out with this code

```
ul{ text-align: center;}
li{ list-style: none; display: inline-block;}
a{ color:black; text-decoration: none; padding:15px; display: block;}
li ul{ position: absolute; background-color: aquamarine; position: absolute; width:100%; left:0; display: none;}
li ul li{ position: relative;}
li ul li ul{ background-color:black; padding:15px; width:300px;}
li ul li ul li{ border-bottom:1px solid #fff; display: block; text-align: left;}
li ul li ul li a{ display: block; color:#fff;}
```

and my menu structure

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>
       <a href="#">Home_1</a>
       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="#">2323</a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
           <li><a href="#">2323</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">2323</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">2323</a></li>
       </ul> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home-3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have 2 level sub menu

```
$('nav li ul').addClass('sub-menu');
    $('nav ul li').hover(function(){
       if($(this).hasClass('active')==false){
           $('nav ul li').removeClass('active');
           $('.sub-menu').slideUp();
           $(this).addClass('active');
           $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideDown();
       }else{
           $('nav ul li').removeClass('active');
           $('.sub-menu').slideUp();
       }
    });
```

My problem is slide down is not working properly, can u tell me what is the mistake in above jquery code.

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: What is the point of `$('nav ul li').removeClass('active');` in both if and else block??

Comment: slide down is not happening properly @isabellnc

Comment: @achu, but what error are you getting in the console?

Comment: i am not getting any error on console @JonathanM

Comment: Can you post a live page or jsfiddle to help us see what's happening?

Comment: [http://aakko.in/demo/test/] see this link @JonathanM

Comment: when i hover home the mega menu want to slide down, then i hover the mega menu link i want open the back color sub menu this should happen one by one @JonathanM

Comment: @JonathanM can u help me to resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Here you go . This is just a sample and I tried to make it as simple as possible without changing most of your code. I used `>` in your selector to exactly point to its first child and `stop()` to stop the animation  and clear animation queues so it does not repeats the animation again and again</strike>.

**Updated:**
Here you go again. The animation still flickers when you hover on it multiple time quickly ( I expect you to solve it ).  I am using `stop()` to stop the animation  and clear animation queues so it does not repeats the animation again and again. You can remove the stop and try hovering above the menu multiple time and you will see the result.

```js
$(function(){
    $('nav  ul  li').hover(function(e){
         $(this).find('ul:eq(0)').stop(true, true).slideDown();
    },function(){
    $(this).find('ul:eq(0)').stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
})
```

```css
ul{ text-align: center;}
li{ list-style: none; display: inline-block;}
a{ color:black; text-decoration: none; padding:15px; display: block;}
li ul{ position: absolute; background-color: aquamarine; position: absolute; width:100%; left:0; display: none;}
li ul li{ position: relative;}
li ul li ul{ background-color:black; padding:15px; width:300px;}
li ul li ul li{ border-bottom:1px solid #fff; display: block; text-align: left;}
li ul li ul li a{ display: block; color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>
       <a href="#">Home_1</a>
       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="#">2323</a>
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
           <li><a href="#">2323</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">2323</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">2323</a></li>
       </ul> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home-3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**However I should say there are lots of other jquery plugins available for multi layer menu out there check it out. Some are entirely done using CSS.**

Comment: the two sub menus are slide down at same time, i want to slide down on by one when i hover the parent li only @bipen

Comment: i can do with this in css but i want to do this using jquery @bipen

Comment: @achu I have no idea why you want to do it in jquery when you can do it with CSS.  I am guessing you want to learn it which you won't be able to, if I solve all your problems right . Anyways I have updated the code.  There are flickers in animation which I expect you to fix it . Good way to learn actaully. Let me know. Happy coding

Answer (score -1):

Please check the updated code on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/f7oqkr3r/5/)
You have problem in slide up slide down code problem and addClass removeClass logic

Html:-

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>
       <a href="#">Home_1</a>
       <ul>
           <li class="innerNavBar">
               <a href="#">2323</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu2">
                   <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
           <li><a href="#">2323</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">2323</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">2323</a></li>
       </ul> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home-3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:-

```
$(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideUp();
   }else{
    $(this).addClass('active');
       $('.sub-menu').slideDown();
       $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideDown();  
   }
   }
});

$('.innerNavBar').hover(function(){
   if($($(this).children()).hasClass('sub-menu2')){
   if($(this).hasClass('active')){
       $(this).removeClass('active');
       $('.sub-menu').slideUp();
       $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu2').slideUp();
   }else{
    $(this).addClass('active');
       $('.sub-menu2').slideDown();
       $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu2').slideDown();  
   }
   }
});Css:-

ul{ text-align: center;}
li{ list-style: none; display: inline-block;}
a{ color:black; text-decoration: none; padding:15px; display: block;}
li ul{ position: absolute; background-color: aquamarine; position: absolute; width:100%; left:0; display: none;}
li ul li{ position: relative;}
li ul li ul{ background-color:black; padding:15px; width:300px;}
li ul li ul li{ border-bottom:1px solid #fff; display: block; text-align: left;}
li ul li ul li a{ display: block; color:#fff;}
```

Comment: Is this an answer/correction? The fiddle still misbehaves.

Comment: Yes your correct, fiddle example is not working fine @JonathanM

Comment: Please check is it working for you or not i updated the code on fiddle

Comment: i checked, this not correct one, the two sub menus are slide down at same time, i want to slide down one by one when i hover the parent li mega menu want to slide down, then when i hover the mega menu link that black color submenu wants to slide down @Kabali

Comment: Ohh so i just corrected that one even i will update that too dont worry

Comment: thank you for your reply, i am wating for your reply @Kabali